# Getting session variables in PHP ajax response pages

Tags: php, ajax, session

I've several pages who are called by ajax to print a response,
The pages uses `$_SESSION` variables, so I have to use `session_start()`.
I noticed that from time to time the pages erase the session data (and user gets disconnected) , i'm using a bit different  `session_start()` :

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'pentago'; // Set a custom session name
    $secure = false; // Set to true if using https.
    $httponly = false; // This stops javascript being able to access the session id.
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1); // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params(); // Gets current cookies params.
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams['lifetime'], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
    session_name($session_name); // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_start(); // Start the php session
    session_regenerate_id(true); // regenerated the session, delete the old one.
}
```

Is there something in my custom `session_start()` that causes the response pages to delete the session ?

Thank you.

Comment: why all of this? all you really need is `session_start()`. regenerating ids occasionally is a good idea, but not required, especially not on every request.

Comment: So what should I leave in there ? the cookies commands and the `session_start()`? I still want the user to use cookies.

Comment: the session name and use only cookies stuff should be in the php.ini, so you don't have to run this code on every page you do. but literally, all you really should need is session_start().